# How to pass column names having spaces to sqoop --map-column-java

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, avro

I have to import data using sqoop, my source column names are having spaces in between them, so while I am adding it in `--map-column-java` parameter getting the error.

**Sample Sqoop import:**

> sqoop import --connect jdbc-con --username "user1" --query "select * from table where \$CONDITIONS" --target-dir /target/path/ -m 1 --map-column-java data col1=String, data col2=String, data col3=String --as-avrodatafile

**Column names:**

```
data col1,
data col2,
data col3
```

**Error:**

> 19/03/07 07:31:55 DEBUG sqoop.Sqoop: Malformed mapping.  Column mapping should be the form key=value[,key=value]*
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed mapping.  Column mapping should be the form key=value[,key=value]*
>           at org.apache.sqoop.SqoopOptions.parseColumnMapping(SqoopOptions.java:1355)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.SqoopOptions.setMapColumnJava(SqoopOptions.java:1375)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.tool.BaseSqoopTool.applyCodeGenOptions(BaseSqoopTool.java:1363)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.applyOptions(ImportTool.java:1011)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.tool.SqoopTool.parseArguments(SqoopTool.java:435)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:135)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)
>   Malformed mapping.  Column mapping should be the form key=value[,key=value]*

Comment: This answer will help you.
[sqoop issue with space column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27572527/how-to-support-column-names-with-spaces-using-sqoop-import)

Comment: I tried with that by passing `data col` getting col not found error.

Comment: Tried as below :

sqoop import --connect jdbc-con --username "user1" --query "select * from table where \$CONDITIONS" --target-dir /target/path/ -m 1 --map-column-java "datacol1=String, datacol2=String, datacol3=String"--as-avrodatafile

getting error: ERROR tool.ImportTool: Import failed: Cannot convert SQL type 2005

Comment: Tried passing all columns in --map-column-java , still throwing error:

ERROR tool.ImportTool: Import failed: Cannot convert SQL type 2005

Comment: we have 3 columns of type 2005: Found COLNAME of type [2005, 2147483647, 0]. I see that the datatype for that COL in SQL server is nvarchar with max_length = -1
so i tried with map-col-java on those col to convert them to string. Still getting same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Able to resolve this issue:

**1. Spaces issue:**
sqoop import --connect jdbc-con --username "user1" --query "select * from table where \$CONDITIONS" --target-dir /target/path/ -m 1 --map-column-java "data col1=String, data col2=String, data col3=String" --as-avrodatafile

**2. ERROR tool.ImportTool: Import failed: Cannot convert SQL type 2005:**
   3 columns in source are having 2005 and nvarchar added them in --map-column-java resolved this issue

**3**. org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter$AppendWriteException: org.apache.avro.UnresolvedUnionException: Not in union ["null","long"]: 1****

This is causing due to using * in select query, so modified sqoop query as:

sqoop import --connect jdbc-con --username "user1" --query "select [col1,data col2,data col3] from table where \$CONDITIONS" --target-dir /target/path/ -m 1 --map-column-java "data col1=String, data col2=String, data col3=String" --as-avrodatafile

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of using you can use this one method
I have used it and it works**

**here I am casting the columns to string so that timestamp could not change to int**

> keep note of that point It will help you to make your string properly
>
> ```
> address = <localhost/server-ip-address/>
>
> port = put your database port number
> ```
>
> **Sqoop is expecting the comma-separated list of mapping in form 'name of column'='new type'**
>
> ```
> columns-name =  give your database column name of timestamp or date time to date
>
>
> database-name = give your datbase name 
>
> database-user-name = put your user name 
>
> password = put your password
> ```

**demo to understand the code properly**

```
sqoop import  --map-column-java "columns-name=String"    --connect jdbc:postgresql://address:port/database-name     --username user-name     --password  database-password --query "select * from demo where \$CONDITIONS;"  -m 1 --target-dir /jdbc/star --as-parquetfile  --enclosed-by '\"'
```

**demo of code for single-column**

```
sqoop import  --map-column-java "date_of_birth=String"    --connect jdbc:postgresql://192.168.0.1:1928/alpha     --username postgres     --password  mysecretpass --query "select * from demo where \$CONDITIONS;"  -m 1 --target-dir /jdbc/star --as-parquetfile  --enclosed-by '\"'
```

**demo of code for dealing with multiple columns**

```
sqoop import  --map-column-java "date_of_birth=String,create_date=String"    --connect jdbc:postgresql://192.168.0.1:1928/alpha     --username postgres     --password  mysecretpass --query "select * from demo where \$CONDITIONS;"  -m 1 --target-dir /jdbc/star --as-parquetfile  --enclosed-by '\"'
```